# how do i get the window url from inside "edit this bookmark" popup, in a firefox addon?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

okay the extension i'm coding, has a button inside the "edit this bookmark" popup, 
Now, when the button is clicked it's supposed to call a `javascript alert : "you are in website url:"+window.location.href` displaying the browser URL 
 but when i test it out, window.location.href only stores
 `browser.xul` page `chrome://browser/content/browser.xul` so is there a way i can get the actual URL?

Answer (score 1):

`gBrowser.selectedBrowser.contentWindow.location.href` gives the window url in the scope of browser.xul

Comment: I like how you used `.selectedBrowser` it makes for less confusion to people when they see the shortcut `gBrowser.contentWindow.location.href`. selectedBrowser helps people learn the meaning of browser in firefox dev, (that there is a xul browser element, and this is where pages load in the xul of the firefox browser).